# Android: How can I make a Drawable array?

Tags: android

How can I make an array that handles some of my images so that I can use it like this?:

```
ImageView.setImageResource(image[1]);
```

I hope I explained well...

Comment: take a look at this [Android storing R.drawable. ids in XML array][1], its using typed array in array.xml.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945678/android-storing-r-drawable-ids-in-xml-array

Answer (score 82, accepted):

To do that, you don't want an array of Drawable's, just an array of resource identifiers, because 'setImageResource' takes those identifiers. How about this:

```
int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.thingOne, R.drawable.thingTwo};
// later...
myImageView.setImageResource(myImageList[i]);
```

Or for a resizable version:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myImageList = new ArrayList<>();
myImageList.add(R.drawable.thingOne);
// later...
myImageView.setImageResource(myImageList.get(i));
```

Comment: How would you achieve adding images to an int[] but have it search through all files and add instead of explicitly naming each file to add?

Answer (score 12):

First of all you have to get all drawable IDs of your pictures with the following method:

```
int android.content.res.Resources.getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

For example, you could read all drawable IDs in a loop:

```
int drawableId = resources.getIdentifier("picture01", "drawable", "pkg.of.your.java.files");
                                          picture02...
                                          picture03...
```

..and then save them into an Array of Bitmaps:

```
private Bitmap[] images;
images[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, drawableId);
```

Now you are able to use your images as array.

Answer (score 3):

with respect of @Bevor, you can use `getResources()` method instead of `android.content.res.Resources` like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> imgArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        imgArr.add(getResources().getIdentifier("picture"+i, "drawable", "pkg.of.your.java.files"));
    }
```

Usage:

```
imageView.setImageResource((int)imgArr.get(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] arrDrawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrDrawerItems); // Your string title array

// You use below array to create your custom model like
TypedArray arrDrawerIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.arrDrawerIcons);

for(int i = 0; i < arrDrawerItems.length; i++) {
    drawerItemDataList.add(new DrawerItemModel(arrDrawerItems[i], arrDrawerIcons.getResourceId(i, -1), i == 0 ? true : false));
}
drawerItemAdapter = new DrawerItemAdapter(this, drawerItemDataList);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(drawerItemAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin code:
initialize below class:

```
private var drawables: Array<Drawable>
```

initialize drawables in 1 line:

```
drawables = arrayOf(
            model.getDrawable(R.drawable.welcome_1),
            model.getDrawable(R.drawable.welcome_2),
            model.getDrawable(R.drawable.welcome_3)
        )
```

my model.getDrawable() is

```
fun getDrawable(id: Int): Drawable {
    return ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.resources, id, context.theme)!!
}
```

set drawable to imageView

```
holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawables[position])
```