# Storing R.drawable IDs in XML array

Tags: android, arrays, android-xml, android-drawable, android-resources

I would like to store drawable resources' ID in the form of `R.drawable.*` inside an array using an XML values file, and then retrieve the array in my activity.

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "inside an array using XML"?

Comment: a values file. eg, strings.xml

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this. Could you provide a bit more background about why you want to do it this way?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do something way more complicated than necessary.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to store the id for images that will be displayed in a listview.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

You use a [typed array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) in `arrays.xml` file within your `/res/values` folder that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <integer-array name="random_imgs">
        <item>@drawable/car_01</item>
        <item>@drawable/balloon_random_02</item>
        <item>@drawable/dog_03</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

Then in your activity, access them like so:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);

// get resource ID by index, use 0 as default to set null resource
imgs.getResourceId(i, 0)

// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, 0));

// recycle the array
imgs.recycle();
```

Comment: defValue - Value to return if the attribute is not defined or not a resource. I'm pretty sure it will set the imageview blank if it has to use the default -1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getResourceId(int, int)

Comment: For anyone else stuck on where exactly to put this arrays.xml file, I put it in res/values and things worked. I also had to rename it to array.xml instead of arrays, for some reason.

Comment: Is "string-array" correct? Shouldn't it just be "array"?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: You should be using 0 instead of -1 for the default id. -1 is a valid resource id, while 0 is the null resource.

Comment: The correct element for a [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) is `<array>` not `<string-array>`.

Comment: @Nishad **-1 stands for default value if index is catched with error** <br><br>`getResourceId(int index, int defValue)`
<br>***Retrieves the resource identifier for the attribute at index.***

Comment: Why do we have to use recycle at the end?

Comment: Use length() to get the element count for a TypedArray.

Comment: IMO, using an `arrays.xml` file obscures the content. I personally add all my string arrays in a regular `strings.xml` file while I place my integer arrays in the `integer.xml` file. Actually, Android doesn't care how do you name all these resource files (you could even mix strings, styles, integers and everything in the same single file), so I prefer to make it clear what they contain.

Answer (score 33):

In the `value` folder create `xml` file name it `arrays.xml`
add the data to it in this way

```
<integer-array name="your_array_name">
    <item>@drawable/1</item>
    <item>@drawable/2</item>
    <item>@drawable/3</item>
    <item>@drawable/4</item>
</integer-array>
```

Then obtain it to your code this way

```
private TypedArray img;
img = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.your_array_name);
```

Then to use a `Drawable` of these in the `img` `TypedArray` for example as an `ImageView` `background` use the following code

```
ImageView.setBackgroundResource(img.getResourceId(index, defaultValue));
```

where `index` is the `Drawable` index.
`defaultValue` is a value you give if there is no item at this `index`

For more information about `TypedArray` visit this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html

Answer (score 17):

You can use this to create an array of other resources, such as drawables. Note that the array is not required to be homogeneous, so you can create an array of mixed resource types, but you must be aware of what and where the data types are in the array.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/home</item>
        <item>@drawable/settings</item>
        <item>@drawable/logout</item>
    </array>
    <array name="colors">
        <item>#FFFF0000</item>
        <item>#FF00FF00</item>
        <item>#FF0000FF</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

And obtain the resources in your activity like this

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(0);

TypedArray colors = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.colors);
int color = colors.getColor(0,0);
```

Enjoy!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin, you can do as:-

```
 <integer-array name="drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/drawer_home</item>
</integer-array>
```

**You will get array of Image from the resource as `TypedArray`**

```
 val imageArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawer_icons)
```

**get resource ID by the index**

```
imageArray.getResourceId(imageArray.getIndex(0),-1)
```

**OR you can set imageView's resource to the id**

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageArray.getResourceId(imageArray.getIndex(0),-1))
```

**and in last recycle the array**

```
imageArray.recycle()
```

Answer (score 2):

kotlin way could be this:

```
fun Int.resDrawableArray(context: Context, index: Int, block: (drawableResId: Int) -> Unit) {
  val array = context.resources.obtainTypedArray(this)
  block(array.getResourceId(index, -1))
  array.recycle()
}

R.array.random_imgs.resDrawableArray(context, 0) {
  mImgView1.setImageResource(it)
}
```