# Android Storing Drawable In Array

Tags: android, spinner, drawable, arrays

I'm currently trying to access and use an image in place of text in a Spinner I'm using.
The below code works, if I were to use text specifically instead of drawables.

I previously referenced this question: [Storing R.drawable IDs in XML array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945678/android-storing-r-drawable-ids-in-xml-array)

Hoping to fix my problem, however I was unable to figure out exactly where I was going wrong. I seem to continuously get:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at '^index_1' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher.png')
```

Etc, for each image. Each drawable exists and is in the appropriate spot, the code is apparently beyond my understanding.

```
<string-array name="rating_array">
        <item>N/A</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_launcher.png</item>
        <item>@drawable/smile.png</item>
        <item>@drawable/stale.png</item>
        <item>@drawable/sad.png</item>
        <item>@drawable/angry.png</item>
    </string-array>
```

[Edit]

I have rid myself of the .png extensions. I'm still receiving the same error, however.
Any additional suggestions?

Also getting:

I got rid of those errors, I'm now getting:

\res\layout\activity_main.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'contentDescription' with value '@string/rate_main').
\res\layout\activity_main.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'entries' with value '@array/category_array').
\res\layout\activity_main.xml:36: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'entries' with value '@array/rating_array').
res\layout\activity_main.xml:46: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'entries' with value '@array/descriptor_array').
res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').

As errors, however when I remove these list files, I have no issue.
Also, for some reason it's saying it's affecting my other arrays however "rating_array" is the only one that's not your standard text list.

Code in it's entirety concerning this:

String.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="rating_array">
        <item>N/A</item>

    </string-array>

    <string-array name="descriptor_array">
        <item>N/A</item>
        <item>Price</item>
        <item>Service</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="category_array">
        <item>N/A</item>
        <item>Restaurants</item>
        <item>Hotels</item>
        <item>Theater</item>
        <item>Shopping</item>
    </string-array>



    <string name="app_name">W!NK</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>



    <string name="rate_main">Rate</string>


</resources>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinbutton1, spinbutton2, spinbutton3;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){
        spinbutton1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinbutton1);
            spinbutton1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
        spinbutton2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinbutton2);
            spinbutton2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
        spinbutton3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinbutton3);
            spinbutton3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }




}
```

Comment: Post your code to access the above

Answer (score 1):

as in error :

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at '^index_1'
>   with value '@drawable/ic_launcher.png')

because you are currently passing drawable image extension(.png) with drawable names in `string-array`. so you will need to remove file extensions(.png) for drawable names which you are using in `string-array`change it as:

```
<string-array name="rating_array">
        <item>N/A</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item>@drawable/smile</item>
        <item>@drawable/stale</item>
        <item>@drawable/sad</item>
        <item>@drawable/angry</item>
    </string-array>
```