# Custom ArrayList Adaptor - Displaying Icons in the ActionBar List

Tags: android, listview, icons, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to add icons to my ActionBar (v7). I created a custom ArrayAdapter

I want to display the appropriate icon next to the list item. However, I am getting the correct icon upon slection, not in the list itself

[image: Menu non-functioning]

```
public class ObjectsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


private final Context context;
private final String[] values;


public ObjectsArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.objects_type_list, R.id.label, values);

    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.objects_type_list, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    if (s.equals("Wall")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_email);
        Log.d("IMG", "Found Wall");
    } else if (s.equals("Door")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        Log.d("IMG", "Found Door");
    } else if (s.equals("Stairs")) {
        Log.d("IMG", "Found Stairs");
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_email);
    } else {
        Log.d("IMG", "Default");
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_email);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

And the list Layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
 >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I set the actual list items to contain the correct icons ?

Update:

Must be something to do with the fact that getView is not called OnCreate ?

```
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
            new ObjectsArrayAdapter(actionBar.getThemedContext(),
                                                                        Ipsum.Types), this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, in case anyone has a similar issue.

If your ArrayAdapter implements `public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` rather than `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent` - see SpinnerAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html

The view is initialized correctly

Answer (score 1):

Create an array.xml file and add your images, just like this:

```
<string-array name="random_imgs">
    <item>@drawable/car_01</item>
    <item>@drawable/balloon_random_02</item>
    <item>@drawable/dog_03</item>
</string-array>
```

Then add this code in your activity:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);
//get resourceid by index
imgs.getResourceId(i, -1)
// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
</resources>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945678/android-storing-r-drawable-ids-in-xml-array)