# How can i add icons to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello everyOne i ask how can i add some icons to arrayList in this code

```
spinnerList = new ArrayList();
        spinnerList.add("Item1") ;
        spinnerList.add("Item2");
        spinnerList.add("Item3");
        spinnerList.add("Item4");


         adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
        removeItemInActionBar(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the icons to the ArrayList directly, but you can use a custom Adapter that adds an icon next to the text. An example of how to do this can be found here: [Custom ArrayList Adaptor - Displaying Icons in the the ActionBar List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161369/custom-arraylist-adaptor-displaying-icons-in-the-the-actionbar-list).