# Is it a good thing to write logic based on the hex value of id generated in R.java android

Tags: android

This what I have seen in an android application. They have a number of image buttons with ids

```
R.java :
        public static final int img1=0x7f090080;
        public static final int img2=0x7f090081;
        public static final int img3=0x7f090082;
        public static final int img4=0x7f090083;
        public static final int img5=0x7f090084;
        public static final int img6=0x7f090085;
        public static final int img7=0x7f090086;
        public static final int img8=0x7f090087;
```

In one of the activity they are traversing a for loop like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NoOfButtons; i++) {
    if (i == pos) {
        ((ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.img1 + i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.circular_pagination_red);
    } else {
        ((ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.img1 + i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.circular_pagination_brown);
}
```

I want to know how much safe and advisable it is.
One thing this is working absolutely fine. I been a part of this from months and never seen a problem in this logic. But still it irks me a bit.

Note : I am not getting any error and I know the alternate solution also. My only concern is if it is not advisable/safe I want to know why? Another is scenarios where it can create havoc for me. I have a good understanding about R.java.

Comment: `R.java` generates itself. you shouldn't edit it. If you're getting any error then check your `layout` file

Comment: I am not getting any error , as I already said its working fine.

Comment: You could use **reflection**. See my answer.

Comment: Who so ever give a downvote to question Please comment and explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Though this might work OK most of the times, this is definitely not advisable. The R class is generated automatically thus you have no control over it and it could change. There is a solution to this problem using a typed array in resources. Check for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6945827/4584675).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use **reflection**.

Add this method to your code:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int myID =
    getResourceID("your_resource_name", "drawable", getApplicationContext());
```

Note: no path (and no extension, in case of images).