# Could android store drawable ids like an integer-array?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I want a `drawable` id array of integer values which I can store like an `integer-array` in `res/values/XXX.xml` by using `integer-array` tag. Below is integer-array declared in `strings.xml`

```
<integer-array name="icons">
     <item>1</item>
     <item>2</item>
     <item>3</item>
     <item>4</item>
</integer-array>
```

But I want to store drawable image ids like `@drawable/someImage` as an integer array in xml.

**OR** Is there any alternatives to store drawable integer ids as an integer array in xml.

Comment: I am not sure this is exactly you are looking for  but try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945678/android-storing-r-drawable-ids-in-xml-array

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think `TypedArray` is what you are looking for. I have samples using it. If you are interested, take a look at codes below:

**First**, `integer-array` in `res/values/arrays.xml`:

```
<integer-array name="frag_home_ids">
    <item>@drawable/frag_home_credit_return_money</item>
    <item>@drawable/frag_home_transfer</item>
    <item>@drawable/frag_home_balance</item>
    <item>@drawable/frag_home_charge</item>
    <item>@drawable/frag_home_finance_cdd</item>
    <item>@drawable/frag_home_finance_ybjr</item>
    <item>@drawable/frag_home_more</item>
</integer-array>
```

**Second**, get resource integer values programmatically:

```
TypedArray tArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
            R.array.frag_home_ids);
int count = tArray.length();
int[] ids = new int[count];
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    ids[i] = tArray.getResourceId(i, 0);
}
//Recycles the TypedArray, to be re-used by a later caller. 
//After calling this function you must not ever touch the typed array again.
tArray.recycle();
```

**Third**, call the integer values like this:

```
holder.iv.setImageResource(ids[position]);
```

Of course, you can get integer values of `string`, `color`, `integer`, `layout`, `menu`...in this way.

I hope these codes will inspire you.

Comment: Don't forget to recycle the typed array at the end of the second step by calling tArray.recycle(), to avoid memory problems.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at documentation, specifically [More Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) article. Quote:

> Typed Array
>   A TypedArray defined in XML. You can use this to create an array of other resources, such as drawables.
>
> EXAMPLE:
>   XML file saved at res/values/arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/home</item>
        <item>@drawable/settings</item>
        <item>@drawable/logout</item>
    </array>
    <array name="colors">
        <item>#FFFF0000</item>
        <item>#FF00FF00</item>
        <item>#FF0000FF</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [string array](https://developer.android.com/samples/MediaRouter/res/values/arrays.html).

Extract:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="media_names">
        <item>Big Buck Bunny</item>
        <item>Elephants Dream</item>
        <item>Sintel</item>
        <item>Tears of Steel</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="media_uris">
        <item>http://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4</item>
        <item>http://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream_277/elephant_dreams_640_512kb.mp4</item>
        <item>http://archive.org/download/Sintel/sintel-2048-stereo_512kb.mp4</item>
        <item>http://archive.org/download/Tears-of-Steel/tears_of_steel_720p.mp4</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

What is it that you want to achieve, I cannot 100% tell you if this is the best choice for you.

Comment: @Knossos-i want drawable images to store as an array in xml file so i can use them directly in my adapter.

Comment: Then you want to take a look at @aga's answer. That will do what you want.