# How to get drawable resource from boolean resource

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-selector

Is there a way to get a drawable resource from a boolean resource?

For example:

`bools.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="use_version_1_drawables">true</bool>
</resources>
```

`my_drawable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable_version_1"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable_version_2"/>
</selector>
```

Is there a specific state I should be using because from what I understand they are all related to specific events (checking, focusing, etc). Perhaps I shouldn't be using a selector. I simply want to have one resource I can call upon that's actually linking to two others but will select one based on my bool.

Comment: Which way are you planning to variate the value of `use_version_1_drawables`?

Comment: @art I'm writing a module so I'm intending that when the module is used that all you have to do is add a boolean with id of `user_version_1_drawables` and set it to whatever you want.

Comment: You can use arrays (in xml) of drawable id's. Each array would have two entries,  position 0 for false and position 1 for true.  See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819204/could-android-store-drawable-ids-like-an-integer-array) for how to get the actual drawables

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You can think of a selector as an if/else statement. What you're missing now is your actual state. Here is an example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/gray" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

If you're using it with something like a Checkbox, then just set this selector as a drawable resource for the checkbox, and state_checked will be updated automatically.

EDIT: Problem was slightly more complex, and solved in the comments.

Comment: I'm actually using the drawable as an icon for a navigation item so the `android:state_checked` state doesn't work for me. I don't want to change the drawable based on a checked state, but instead want to just use either or based on my boolean.

Comment: Is this view a custom class you created? Or is it from some navigation component?

Comment: It's just for icons in a menu. The menu is being used for a bottom navigation view.

Comment: Hm. I'll think of something. Best thing I can think of now is inflating different menus depending on that boolean, but that just doesn't seem very right.

Comment: Yeah that's the kind of thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Is defining it as a theme attribute out of the question aswell?

Comment: I hadn't considered that before. I created some custom attributes for my drawables and then setup two app themes (one for version one and one for version two) and it works exactly as expected.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was thinking. :)