# Changing image on imageView in android via java

Tags: java, android

I have a imageView, button inside an activity, 10 pictures that are named from stage1 to stage9.

I need you help to solve some problem

I would like to use a button click to change picture that is on imageView to the next one.

I mean, I want to press on the button, and image view shows stage2 image, I press the button again and stage3 picture will be shown.

I have done this using counter var which count number of clicks and then running if statment to see which picture should go next, but it is too long and it is not possible to have more or less pictures.

I would like to know is there a way to do this, and if possible please show me how.

Thanks

code

```
private void changeImage(int counter) {
    if (counter == 1) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage2);
    } else if (counter == 2) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage3);
    } else if (counter == 3) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage4);
    } else if (counter == 4) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage5);
    } else if (counter == 5) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage6);
    } else if (counter == 6) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage7);
    } else if (counter == 7) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage8);
    } else if (counter == 8) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stage9);
    }       
}
```

bassically this is the code that I am using right now.

It works, but if I want to do it to be more dynamic.

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: Use an array and the length as the counter to make it more dynamic. But, yes, show your code that you are stuck on

Comment: Where are the pictures? Local, or using URL?

Comment: @Danielson all the pictures are local

Comment: @codeMagic your idea is good, but there is still a problem of fillfing of array. How can I do that with images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945678/android-storing-r-drawable-ids-in-xml-array

Answer (score 1):

Just get resource id by name, use like,

```
private void changeImage(int counter) {

     if(counter >= 1 && counter <= 9) // Always check counter value before accessing as resource id
     {
      int counterValue = counter+1;  
      int resourceId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("stage"+counterValue, "drawable",  this.getPackageName()); // Use application context to get package name
      image.setImageResource(resourceId);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried the code but image is not shown.

Comment: @depecheSoul - Have you tried `getPackageName()` ? I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I also tried it with a getPackageName(). I also tried to changed the "stage"+counter to "stage"+counter+".png". Still not working

Comment: Nope you don't have to specified file extension, here id is only be as your R.java file entries.

Comment: You are displaying the next image of whatever counter values is, so in your case it should be like `"stage"+(counter+1)`. Also I suggest you to print `resourceId` before you will set it as image resource.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to tell the vm to update -> 'invalide()'.

Or use Picasso,

```
Picasso.with(Statics.context).load(R.drawable.stageX).error(R.drawable.error_img).resize(width, height).priority(Priority.HIGH).into(image);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have never heard about Picasso(I am still learning).

Comment: It saved me... handles caching, downloading... all you need