# How to put all image in "drawable-xxhdpi" in an array? specifically in "Mat" array?

Tags: android, arrays, image

I still can't figure out how to do this. Retreive all images in the drawable folder and load them in an array:( is this possible? HELP!

Comment: Hoping someone with a good heart will help :(

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.thingOne, R.drawable.thingTwonR,drawable.thingTwo};

ArrayList<Integer> myImageList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myImageList.add(R.drawable.thingOne);
```

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355220/android-how-can-i-make-a-drawable-array)

Comment: Thanks sir.I'll notify you later if this is working. Thanks again

Comment: Sir. Is the "thingone" there the integer id of the image? If that is. How can i get its integer id?

Comment: hii thinkone is image name placeed in drable folder